# Mostrar el valor seleccionado de <v-select> en <v-text-field>?

Tags: javascript, vuetify

Como puedo obtener el valor del  luego mostrarlo en un ,lo que intento hacer es mostrar valor seleccionado de  "select1" y en el campo de  debe de mostrarse "probando1", dejo el código para que me puedan ayudar en el problema que tengo y poder corregir si lo estoy haciendo mal y disculpen los errores es la primera ves que ingreso a esta pagina y me parece genial que ayuden a los novatos que recién empezamos, gracias.

Este es mi código para seleccionar y mostrar.

```
<template>
  <v-layout align-start>
    <v-flex>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="3" md="3">
            <v-select v-model="selecionado" :items="items" label="selecciona"></v-select>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="3" md="3">
            <v-text-field v-model="valorseleccionado" label="Valor Seleccionado text2"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

Aqui el código java script

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selecionado: "",
      items: [
        { text: "select1", text2: "probando1", value: 1 },
        { text: "select2", text2: "probando2", value: 2 }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto:

Cuando el `select` cambiar activa `changeState` y se actualiza `selecionado`.

```
<template>
  <v-layout align-start>
    <v-flex>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="3" md="3">
            <v-select
              :items="items"
              label="selecciona"
              @change="(valor) => changeState(valor)"
            ></v-select>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="3" md="3">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="selecionado"
              label="Valor Seleccionado text2"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selecionado: "",
      items: [
        { text: "select1", text2: "probando1", value: 1 },
        { text: "select2", text2: "probando2", value: 2 },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeState(valor) {
      this.selecionado = this.items[valor - 1].text2;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Aquí tienes una [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-bell-yce5u?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) que funciona.

Comment: No sería más sencillo usar la misma variable en el v-model de los dos componentes, text field y select? O hay alguna razón por la que usas @change y dos variables?